# Access values in strange Objective-C block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I ve got a very strange test task. In header file there is a function:

```
NSString *AppendString(NSString *string, void (^block)(NSString *stringToAppend));
```

It should append one string to another using block. In my opinion I should run it like this:

```
NSString *newString = AppendString(@"firstString", ^(NSString *stringToAppend){
    stringToAppend = @"secondString";
});
```

How implement this function? I have no idea how to deal with blocks in C-style function. Rewrting base function in Objective-C style is prohibited. Thanks for any help and sorry for my english.

Edit:

Declaration:

```
NSString *AppendString(NSString *string, void (^block)(NSString *stringToAppend));
```

Implementation(not sure):

```
NSString *AppendString(NSString *string, void (^block)(NSString *stringToAppend)){
    // Logic should be here
    // No idea how to access to block variables here
    // I need to concatenate string and stringToAppend(string+stringToAppend)
    return *Result of calculation(NSString*)*
}
```

Using:

```
NSString *newString = AppendString(@"firstString", ^(NSString *stringToAppend){
    // no logic here, just block parameter assignment
    // is it possible to assign stringToAppend here and access to it's variable inside using?
    stringToAppend = @"secondString";
});
```

How to write correct implementation?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Is this homework? If it is homework, then it would be a good exercise to write down clearly and precisely what you want to do. For example, if you have a spec for a C function, then it would be good to know that. It is absolutely essential that you learn to write down what you actually want to achieve, otherwise it is quite impossible to ever write code that does what you want it to do.

Comment: Please look on my edit.

Answer (score 1):

This function pass NSString inside the block so you need to save that string not assign to it:

```
// Declare new block variable (you can assign data to it inside block) to save string
__block NSString *newString = @"";

AppendString(@"firstString", ^(NSString *stringToAppend){
    // Save variable returned by block in variable defined above
    newString = stringToAppend;
});
// Log result to the console
NSLog(@"Result: %@", newString);
```

//EDITED

```
//1. Declaration
// (^block) - this define name of your block, in this case the name is - block
// You don't have to use NSString the data is returned by block, not function
void AppendString(NSString *string, void (^block)(NSString *stringToAppend));

//1. Implementation function doesn't return the data, the data is returned by block:
void AppendString(NSString *string, void (^block)(NSString *stringToAppend)){
    block(string);
}

//1.Using:
__block NSString *result = @"";

    AppendString(@"test", ^(NSString *stringToAppend) {
        result = stringToAppend;
    });
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);


//2. Declaration
// You return the data by function and by block
NSString* AppendString(NSString *string, void (^block)(NSString *stringToAppend));

//2. Implementation function returns the data, and block too:
NSString* AppendString(NSString *string, void (^block)(NSString *stringToAppend)){
    block(string);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - returned by function", string];
}
//2.Using:
__block NSString *result = @"";

    NSString *funcResult =  AppendString(@"test", ^(NSString *stringToAppend) {
        result = stringToAppend;
    });
    NSLog(@"Block result: %@", result);
    NSLog(@"Function result: %@", funcResult);
```

There are two examples to create and use function you want.
See both and the comments should explain most how they works.

Comment: Is it possible to pass 'stringToAppend' inside _using_ and access to it in _implementation_? See edited question.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand what you trying to do. You can assign string to stringToAppend inside the block, as in your example stringToAppend = @"secondString"; but you don't use it later.

Comment: Is it a local assignment or I can use it inside implementation? I need access stringToAppend to make concatenation.

Comment: You should read a bit about the block. If you talking about implementation of this function you don't touch the block variable (I'm talking about your example). You should make string concatenation on *string variable and pass it to the block:  void AppendString(NSString *string, void (^block)(NSString *stringToAppend)){    string = @"secondString";
    block(string);
}